# Is there a dataset of ICDs which could indicate a severe medical condition in the future?

Tags: diagnosis, icd-intrntl-classif-disea

As a software developer I asked myself, if there is a public dataset of ICDs which could indicate a severe medical condition in the future?

e.g. F06.7, F32.X, F33.X could led to F00.0

Or is it not possible to see such a correlation on the base of ICDs?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?